# Why visual c++ 2010 express fails to install on windows xp service pack 3?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded the web installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP) but when trying to install it just fails:

> Setup could not install the following
>   component:   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   4

Or is it true that VCE2010 can only be installed on 64 bit os?

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it true that VCE2010 can only be installed on 64 bit os?

No, It isn't true.
I installed both Visual C# 2010 Express, and Visual C++ 2010 Express on a Windows-7 32-bit netbook.
.NET Framework 4.0 supports Windows XP SP3, on both 64-bit and 32-bit architectures; its prerequisites (Windows Installer 3.1, and Internet Explorer 5.01) should be fulfilled by Windows XP SP3.

Comment: I'm now trying to download the iso image , no other way if still not working..

Comment: Failed again...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an internet connection on this computer? I Guess the Webinstallation reloads some files during installation process. You could try to download and install .NET Framework 4 manually [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en), but I assume that there will be more than .NET missing.

Answer (score 0):

Although it didn't work for you, using the ISO images worked for me. You can download the 2010 ISOs from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso), and run them with [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite).